# How to use LOWER/UPPER in Oracle SQL Developer Package

Tags: sql, vb.net, plsql

I have created a SQL package within Oracle SQL Developer for my site i have made within VIsual Studio 2013. The package basically takes input from a search box and locates all the details from a database table based on the search and then returns it back to the site within a table.

I know this may sound simple but i am a bit stuck but what i am trying to do is to let the user search with upper or lower case letters to make sure the data is returned because at the moment when i search it has to match how the data is stored exactly within the table which is not user friendly.

Please could someone help me with where in the package/SQL i would change so the user can use either upper or lower case letters.

My Package Code;

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY USER_PRO AS


procedure emp_pro_search
(
  get_emp_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_login_search IN varchar2,
    p_firstname_search IN varchar2,
    p_surname_search IN varchar2,
    p_empnumb_search IN varchar2,
    p_prolist_search IN varchar2
)
IS
l_login_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_firstname_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_surname_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_empnumb_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_prolist_clause VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN

IF p_login_search IS NOT NULL THEN
  l_login_clause := ' AND LOGIN =''' || p_login_search ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_firstname_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_firstname_clause := ' AND FIRSTNAME =''' || p_firstname_search ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_surname_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_surname_clause := ' AND SURNAME =''' || p_surname_search ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_empnumb_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_empnumb_clause := ' AND EMP_NUMB =''' || p_empnumb_search ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_prolist_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_prolist_clause := ' AND PRO_LIST =''' || p_prolist_search ||'''';
END IF;

OPEN get_user_details FOR
 'SELECT login, emp_id, surname, forename, middlename, date_of_birth, emp_numb, position, ' || 
      'FROM  my_employment_table ' ||
      ' WHERE 1 = 1 ' ||
     l_login_clause ||
     l_firstname_clause ||
     l_surname_clause ||
     l_empnumb_clause ||
     l_prolist_clause ||
     'ORDER BY surname ';

END emp_pro_search;
```

This is my class that calls the package;

```
 Public Shared Function SearchResults(ByVal sLogin As String, ByVal sfirstName As String, ByVal slastName As String, ByVal sempNumber As String, ByVal sproList As String) As DataSet

    Dim oraConnect As New OracleConnection
    oraConnect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mydatabase").ConnectionString

    Dim p_login_search As New OracleParameter
    p_login_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    p_login_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p_login_search.Value = sLoginid

    Dim p_firstname_search As New OracleParameter
    p_firstname_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    p_firstname_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p_firstname_search.Value = sfirstName

    Dim p_surname_search As New OracleParameter
    p_surname_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    p_surname_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p_surname_search.Value = slastName

    Dim p_empnumb_search As New OracleParameter
    p_empnumb_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    p_empnumb_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p_empnumb_search.Value = sEsrnumber

    Dim p_prolist_search As New OracleParameter
    p_prolist_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    p_prolist_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p_prolist_search.Value = sProfnumber

    Dim oraCommand As New OracleCommand
    oraCommand.Connection = oraConnect
    oraCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    oraCommand.CommandText = "USER_PRO.EMP_PRO_SEARCH"


    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("p_RefCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 0, ParameterDirection.Output, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "", DataRowVersion.Current, Nothing))
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(p_login_search)
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(p_firstname_search)
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(p_surname_search)
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(p_empnumb_search)
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(p_prolist_search)

    Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)

    Return ds
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything within quotes is case sensitive in SQL, to perform case insensitive search, way would be to force the search criteria and data to upper/lower case:

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY USER_PRO AS


procedure emp_pro_search
(
  get_emp_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_login_search IN varchar2,
    p_firstname_search IN varchar2,
    p_surname_search IN varchar2,
    p_empnumb_search IN varchar2,
    p_prolist_search IN varchar2
)
IS
l_login_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_firstname_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_surname_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_empnumb_clause VARCHAR2(255);
l_prolist_clause VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN

IF p_login_search IS NOT NULL THEN
  l_login_clause := ' AND UPPER(LOGIN) =''' || UPPER(p_login_search) ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_firstname_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_firstname_clause := ' AND UPPER(FIRSTNAME) =''' || UPPER(p_firstname_search) ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_surname_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_surname_clause := ' AND UPPER(SURNAME) =''' || UPPER(p_surname_search) ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_empnumb_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_empnumb_clause := ' AND EMP_NUMB =''' || p_empnumb_search ||'''';
END IF;

IF p_prolist_search IS NOT NULL THEN
l_prolist_clause := ' AND PRO_LIST =''' || p_prolist_search ||'''';
END IF;
```

---

I haven't added upper clause for "Prolist" - if this is a varchar field, you can change it the same way I have done for first name/last.

Another point to note - this search will work only for exact matches. Add `%` wildcard operator if you don't want to force exact match.

```
OPEN get_user_details FOR
 'SELECT login, emp_id, surname, forename, middlename, date_of_birth, emp_numb, position, ' || 
      'FROM  my_employment_table ' ||
      ' WHERE 1 = 1 ' ||
     l_login_clause ||
     l_firstname_clause ||
     l_surname_clause ||
     l_empnumb_clause ||
     l_prolist_clause ||
     'ORDER BY surname ';

END emp_pro_search;
```